# Signal Processing Basics

Tags: signal, signal-processing

[image]

I am clear with the problem and its solution. But I am curious if it is possible to calculate all possible solutions.

Comment: One possible set of values *is* ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot calculate all of the solutions because there are an infinite number of solutions.

If \$F_S\$ is the sampling frequency then any frequency \$n F_S \pm F_j\$ where \$j\$ is 1, 2, or 3, and \$n\$ is any integer, will be aliased to a frequency overlapping one of your original signal frequencies (\$F_1\$, \$F_2\$, or \$F_3\$), and so produce the observed results.

Comment: I got it. But, what if F4 is not there. Then also there will be infinite  options I guess like (450,625,950) or (450,625,7050).....